# php pass a command to another user's screen session

Tags: php, linux, bash, gnu-screen

I need to have my web server (apache) send the command "list" using PHP to the user "mike"'s GNU screen session.

the apache user is added to the screen session, and in the sudoers file

I've tried many things to get this working, here are some examples:

```
    <?php
            var_dump(exec("sudo -u mike screen -x server1 -p 0 -X stuff \"`printf \"list\r\"`\";"));
    ?>
```

This returned an empty string. Another attempt:

```
    <?php
            var_dump(exec("screen -x mike/server1 -p 0 -X stuff \"`printf \"list\r\"`\";"));
    ?>
```

This returned with the following string: "Cannot opendir /var/run/screen/S-mike: Permission denied"

I've been stuck on this problem for weeks now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi there my name is [chmod](http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/) and you should try this link or google for yourself to understand what I can do.

Comment: /var/run/screen/S-mike has to be 700, otherwise screen won't even work at all

Comment: Are you sure it is 700? What about 755?

Comment: tried & failed, MUST be 700